# How to use session in public direcory in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, public

I set session for getting name of the user when he/she logged-in

but when I want to `echo` it in public directory I can not `echo` and I don't know can I declare

**In controller**

```
session(['sessionName' => 'Karim']);
```

**In public**

```
echo $_SESSION['CKFinder_UserRole']
```

It's give me a **fatal error** to:

> undefined variable

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: You could use Laravels `Auth::user()->name` to get the (user)name of the currently logged in user. Also, you're setting `'sessionName'` but printing `'CKFinder_UserRole'`?! And what do you mean by "_in public directory_"?

Comment: i'm so sorry i made a mistake in question ..in public/plugins/elfinder i echo session name same as controller. i use elfinder and its file manager is in the public directory so i want to set session to let just users that logged in can use file manager

Comment: You could use Laravels `Auth::check()` to ... check if a user is logged in

Comment: so I know but where can I check it? for example in admin controller where admin logged in and can see file manager but the page of the file manager is in the public directory and it has no controller

Comment: IMHO there shouldn't be any "pages" in the `public` folder, "pages" would be created using views. Move your page from `public` to a controller method, add a route so you can use middleware etc. Or, take a look at https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder

Comment: tnx a lot for your answer

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't put .php pages in the public folder.  I've found a few instances where I wanted to do something like what you are describing (I think).  What I ended up doing is setting a $_SESSION variable somewhere, like in a Controller or route, and then accessing the variable in the .php page in the public folder.  That seems to work, but you also, I think need to issue a session_start().  It is probably better practice to use a Controller or other part of the Laravel framework to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this, 
In Controller,

```
return back()->with('name','Hello');
```

in view,

```
{{ Session::get('name') }}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: this is the exaclt point!!! i know how to declare in view but my page is not in view its in public/plugins/elfinder